# Getting a 429 response when attempting to subscribe to calendar

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We previously posted this issue on GitHub regarding concerns over limits for subscribing to calendar changes for rooms: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/5709

The answer we got was that "No, there aren't any [limits] that you should be concerned about."

However, we have started to see this response when trying to register a webhook to subscribe to changes to a calendar of a room:

```
Invalid response - 429: 
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ExtensionError",
    "message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: 429; Reason: Resource 'MaxTotalRequests' has reached limit of '5000'.  Please retry after '9/23/2019 2:20:44 PM']",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "43b79bf3-ddee-4bc3-b436-9caa7bff81ac",
      "date": "2019-09-23T14:20:42"
    }
  }
}
```

We aren't making any large amount of subscriptions, and we only get this response when we are trying to register subscriptions to calendars of users or resources (i.e. not when making other requests to msgraph which are not related to subscriptions). There was a total of 210 subscription related requests made (either subscribing, extending a subscription, or deleting a subscritpion) between 10min before this error and 10min after. Any guidance?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a subscription limit so much as an Exchange Online limit. The message is telling you that you've hit the throttling. Exchange's throttling is based on *n* requests per 10m window. Your code needs to recognize the `HTTP 429` and handle it accordingly.

You find complete details in the [Microsoft Graph throttling guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling).

Comment: We thought of this, but it just seems odd since every time we get the 429 response we were trying to make some subscription related request, never one of the many other requests to MSGraph we make. We checked the number of requests made in a 10min window, there are some hundreds, well below the stated limits.

Comment: I experienced the exact same issue @M.L . We are issuing many graph requests but way less than 5000 / h and only get the throttling message for the subscription endpoints.